# Python function for splitting by indexes

Tags: python, function, split

I have to create a function that recieves a string and list of ints. Function has to split the string by the given indexes and return the result. example:

```
split_by_index("pythoniscool,isn'tit?", [6, 8, 12, 13, 18])
["python", "is", "cool", ",", "isn't", "it?"]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance:

```
def split_by_index(s: str, indexes: List[int]) -> List[str]:
    pass
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying to implement the function yourself first.

Comment: Use a loop or list comprehension that extracts slices using those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the pairs of `indexes`:

```
import itertools

def split_by_index(s: str, indexes: list[int]) -> list[str]:
    return [s[p[0]:p[1]] for p in itertools.pairwise([0]+indexes+[len(s)])]


res = split_by_index("pythoniscool,isn'tit?", [6, 8, 12, 13, 18])
print(res)
```

Out:

```
['python', 'is', 'cool', ',', "isn't", 'it?']
```